# Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_24: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I'm new to keras and I want to build a deep RNN my x_train shape is (1115,106) and my y_train has (1115,11) samples, I can't fix the error I get from the code below:

```
    model_3=Sequential()

    model_3.add(LSTM(64,return_sequences=True,activation='relu'))
    model_3.add(Dropout(0.2))

    model_3.add(LSTM(64,activation='relu'))
    model_3.add(Dropout(0.2))

    model_3.add(Dense(64,activation='relu'))
    model_3.add(Dropout(0.2))

    model_3.add(Dense(11,activation='softmax'))


    model_3.compile(optimizer='adam',
          loss='mean_squared_error',
          metrics=['accuracy'])

    DNN_3= model_3.fit(x_train, y_train,batch_size=64, epochs=100)
```

in ()
     24               metrics=['accuracy'])
     25 
---> 26 DNN_3= model_3.fit(x_train, y_train,batch_size=64, epochs=100)
     27 
     28

ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_24: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2

Answer (score 0):

You have to do two things:

1. LSTM takes input of shape `(n_samples, n_timesteps, n_features)` and that's why it "expected ndim=3". So if you have 1000 data points over time (rounding 1115 for simplicity), then you can reshape your data into shape of `(40, 25, 106)` for input and `(40, 25, 11)` for output. Choices of n_samples and n_timesteps depends on the problem and should be decided by you. This will fix the error you are getting now, but then you would run into another error.
2. Add `return_sequences=True` to the second LSTM as well as it seems you need a many-to-many architecture.